# Probability density function after transformation

Tags: data-transformation, random-variable, density-function

Let $X,Z$ be random variables with probability density functions $p_X,p_Z$.  Suppose $Z=f(X)$, where $f$ is continuous and differentiable.  How is $p_Z$ related to $p_X$?  It's tempting to say $p_Z(z) = p_X(f^{-1}(z))$, but I think that is not correct: I think it might be

$$p_Z(z) = {p_X(f^{-1}(z)) \over f'(f^{-1}(z))},$$

where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$, but I am not sure whether I've got that right.  What is the correct rule?

Answer (score 2):

The correct rule is

$$p_Z(z) = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(z)} {p_X(x) \over f'(x)},$$

as there can be multiple possible values $x$ that satisfy $f(x)=z$.

---

One way to derive this, in the case of a monotonic $f$ (so there is only a single $x$ such that $f(x)=z$), is to consider the cdfs $f_X,f_Z$.  Then we have

$$F_Z(z) = \Pr[Z \le z] = \Pr[f(X) \le z] = \Pr[X \le f^{-1}(x)] = F_X(f^{-1}(z))$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
p_Z(z) &= {d \over dz} F_Z(z) = {d \over dz} (F_X(f^{-1}(z)))\\
&= ({d \over dz} F_X)(f^{-1}(z)) \cdot {d \over dz} f^{-1}(z)\\
&= p_X(f^{-1}(z)) \cdot 1/f'(f^{-1}(z)).
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of the density as the number of particles in a volume in the $dx$ area in X space. The particles in the area $\int p(x)dx$ should be the same with $\int q(y)dy$ in the corresponding area in Y space.

$$
\begin{align}
\int p(x)dx &= \int q(y)dy
\\
x &= f^{-1}(y)
\end{align}
$$

Hence,

$$q(y) = \left\| \frac {p(f^{-1}(y))}{f'(x)} \right\|$$

[image]